# How to convert GWT date format to Datetime in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to convert the below date format to datetime

> 2014-06-04T17:23:45+5:30

the result should be 2014/06/04 17:23:45 PM

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cast and left

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT('2014-06-04T17:23:45+5:30', 19) as datetime)
```